# Azure Backup Vault restore into antoher server

Tags: azure-backup-vault

I have Azure Vault Backups from my old machine that has crashed an not available anymore and I want to restore the files into my other machine. I followed instructions from this doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-restore-windows-server#use-instant-restore-to-restore-data-to-an-alternate-machine

but still getting error that can't restore the file because the server isn't the same.

The specified vault credential file cannot be used as it is not downloaded from the vault associated with this server. (ID: 100110)

Please provide appropriate vault credentials.

Any idea how to resolve this issue? I need my files from other machine!

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and landed on this non-answered question 3 months after it was asked but, for whoever stumbles upon it next, restoring to a machine that is not registered to the same vault as the backed up server appears to be unsupported.

I'm not sure if there is another workaround but my method was to download the vault credentials to a computer that was *not* registered to any vault, registering it using those credentials and then using the standard GUI method to recover the backed up data.

Unfortunately the computer I actually wanted to restore the backup to was already registered to a different vault so presumably I would have had to delete my local backup policy in order to register it to the new vault. It is possible that there is a PowerShell method to instantiate an alternate registration (other than the default on the local machine) but I did not look for it - it does seem possible.